# Переопредление логики конструктора в классе-потомке

Tags: java, ооп

У меня есть некий класс с таким конструктором:

```
public LookupData(LookupData lookupData) {
    if (lookupData != null) {
        this.dictionary = lookupData.getDictionary();//new UserDictionary(lookupData.getDictionary());
        if (lookupData.getConditions() != null) {
            this.conditions = new ArrayList<>(lookupData.getConditions());
        } else {
            this.conditions = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        if (lookupData.getAssignations() != null) {
            this.assignations = new ArrayList<>(lookupData.getAssignations());
        } else {
            this.assignations = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        if (lookupData.getColumnOrderList() != null) {
            this.columnOrderList = new ArrayList<>(lookupData.getColumnOrderList());
        } else {
            this.columnOrderList = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        moveToChild = lookupData.moveToChild;
        getLastVersion = lookupData.getLastVersion;
    }
}
```

Я хочу на основе этого класса создать другой класс, оставив в конструкторе только нужную мне логику. Если я использую наследование, мне нужно вызывать метод супер класса через super, т.е. так:

```
public EntityTablesCountLookupData(LookupData lookupData) {
    super(lookupData);
    if (lookupData != null) {
        this.dictionary = lookupData.getDictionary();
        if (lookupData.getConditions() != null) {
            this.conditions = new ArrayList<>(lookupData.getConditions());
        } else {
            this.conditions = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }
}
```

Но это не работает в моем случае, в итоге выполняется логика суперкласса, и переопределить его поведение я не могу. Что я делаю не так, либо нужно делать что-то другое?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Выносите код из конструктора в `protected` метод `init`;
2. В конструкторе делаете вызов этого метода;
3. В наследниках переопределяете его соответственно потребностям.